# How to show random data every time in recyclerview from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

How do I show random data everytime I open recyclerview

For example if I have a `arraylist` of name

`arraydata={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l}`

In recyclerview it always show in sequence manner means **a** first then **b** then **c** 
Every time we open  recyclerview
It will show the same

Is there anyway to show different sequence everytime i open recyclerview

Currently I am using

```
holder.textitem.setText(arraylistobject.get(position).getTextFun())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Collections` to shuffle your array list of data before passing it to your `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
Collections.shuffle(arraylistobject)
```

Comment: thank you it works i searched about it but might be keyword shuffle was missing thats why i was not getting my desired result

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Random` class from `java.util` package, it's `nextInt()` method returns *pseudorandom* `int`value in range from 0 **inclusive** to value passed as argument **exclusive**:

```
import java.util.*;

Random rand = new Random();
holder.textitem.setText(arraylistobject.get(rand.nextInt(arraylistobject.size()).getTextFun());
```

`rand.nextInt(arraylistobject.size())` in that case returns value from 0 to size of your `arraylistobject` exclusive.